# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nativeservices in java.library.path

Tags: java, matlab

I am using matlab 2014b on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've got some problems while adding a path on matlab and trying to run the scripts. It shows:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nativeservices in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.<clinit>(Prefs.java:152)
at com.mathworks.fatalexit.FatalExitFrame.<init>(FatalExitFrame.java:138)
at com.mathworks.fatalexit.FatalExitFrame$13.run(FatalExitFrame.java:775)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mathworks.services.Prefs.nativeGetPreferencesDirectory()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.nativeGetPreferencesDirectory(Native Method)
at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.getPropertyDirectory(Prefs.java:184)
at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.load(Prefs.java:240)
at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.<clinit>(Prefs.java:160)
at com.mathworks.fatalexit.FatalExitFrame.<init>(FatalExitFrame.java:138)
at com.mathworks.fatalexit.FatalExitFrame$13.run(FatalExitFrame.java:775)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

From what I've seen through other posts is that java isn't able to find the java.library.path or it hasn't been specified.

how can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: its seems , that you have to make exception handling codes. its an native error meaning from the codes written , what library it asking for ? so you can install it

Comment: How did you add the path?

Comment: Did you find the solution @Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install matlab-support
```

and follow the instructions. It will be quite enough.

Comment: It's actually not. I have the same problem and still haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I fixed it using the above command line.